# Create store listener in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am somewhat new to extjs and am trying to create a listener as part of a panel, which is to retrieve the total of count of records in the store, is there any easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` event is not suitable for this purpose as it is fired only when the store is loaded. If you need to monitor changes then you will need the `datachanged` event what is fired whenever any change occurs in the store. I.e. you need something like

```js
Ext.getStore('simpsonsStore').on('datachanged', (store) => {
    panel.down('#count').setHtml('Count: ' + store.count());
})
```

You can use `count()`, `getCount()` or `getTotalCount()` to get the items in the store. The first two does the same and returns the number of items regardless they are written to the proxy. The last returns the count already stored. I.e. `getTotalCount` will only be changed when the store is `sync()`-ed.

[See Fiddle for working example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3c1n)

Answer (score 0):

The store class has events.  The load event will fire when the store reads data from a remote data source. The remote data source should return the total number of records.  The store sets a "totalProperty" The remote store returns this property with a value.  Then you can get the property from the store with getTotalCount().

[Example that returns a totalCount](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#buffer-grid)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the data is stored locally, the exercise I am working required me to add a listener and retrieve the store total and it to the panel title.